# Remote authentication for WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm building a React app which needs to authenticate with a WordPress website, so users can login/reset password etc.

What are my options for authentication? [The official Rest API documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) suggests either Cookie authentication (which is only applicable to a WordPress theme running on the same server, right?) or 'Basic Authentication with Passwords' which seems insecure and not recommended.

For remote applications it suggests using one of two third party plugins:

- [OAuth 1.0a Server](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/ (this is now part of core WordPress but I can't see any endpoints for user creation or password resetting, for example)
- [JSON Web Tokens](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) (JWT)

So, is my only option to install this third party JWT plugin, which doesn't appear to use OAuth, and then create my own login functions?

Surely there's support for secure remote authentication in core WordPress?

Is there an existing React solution out there, preferably using OAuth?